# How to show logout button in header when user is logged in and how to show create account/login when user is logged out Next.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to make it so that when the user is logged in they will have a button on the header saying logout, but when the user is not logged in, the create account and login links will show up, here is my code

Header.js

```
import Link from 'next/link'


export default function Header(){
  return (
    <header className='bg-white border-b flex justify-between p-4'>
        <div className="flex items-center gap-6">
          <Link href={'/'}>FashionFinder </Link>
          <nav className='flex gap-4'>
          <Link href={'/about'}>About</Link>
          <Link href={'/contact'}>Contact</Link>
          <Link href={'/Albums'}>Albums</Link>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <nav className='flex items-center gap-4'>
          <Link href={'/login'}>Sign In</Link>
          <Link href={'/register'}>Create Account</Link>
        </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
```

route.js for logging out

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const response = NextResponse.json({
      message: "Logout successful",
      success: true,
    })

    response.cookies.set("token", "", {httpOnly: true, expires: new Date(0)});

    return response;
    
  } catch (error){
    return NextResponse.json({error: error.message}, {status: 500})
  }
}
```